# Opening ports with iptables

Tags: raspbian, networking, iptables

I'm imaged sd card with latest version of Raspbian : 
http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest

This comes with version of iptables. However there are no rules configured. Do I need to add a rule in order enable connectivity between multiple pi's on network on non standard ports such as 7077, 6066 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, the default is to allow everything.

```
pi@kd-pi ~ $ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: If thats the case why am I seeing all the ports were closed when doing a scan ?